# Named arguments for INTL MessageFormatter with PHP

Tags: php, icu, named-parameters, intl

I would like to use named arguments in a string passed to MessageFormater, like that

```
$fmt = new MessageFormatter("en_US", "My name id {my_name}");
$fmt->format(array('my_name' => 'John'));
```

When I running this code, I obtain the error message :

```
$fmt->getErrorMessage() returns
```

> Number formatting failed: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Whereas

```
$fmt = new MessageFormatter("en_US", "My name id {0}");
$fmt->format(array(0 => 'John'));
```

works well.

icu-project website report that named arguments are supported since ICU 3.8 ([Seen here](http://site.icu-project.org/design/formatting/messageformat/2011q1)), and I use the 4.2.1

Where is the unicorn? PHP doesn't support named arguments for MessageFormatter?
Maybe there is an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in a future (as of today) version of intl. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61871 .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems so. What do you want to hear?

Update: After the OP edited his question

```
echo vsprintf('My name id %s', array('John'));
```

See [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf)

Of course it does not any local-based things.

Comment: I know this way. My texts are sent too translators. I want to avoid %d, %s. It's simplest to translate "My name is {my_name}" than "My name is %s". It's a bad exemple because it's easy to understand the meaning of this sentence, but sometimes it's not the case.